# WebSphere portal 8.5 cluster creation issue

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I am creating a WebSphere portal cluster version 8.5. I am using the configuration wizard for this. In the 'Create a cluster' section, the last section is 'Complete the cluster setup'.While running it , I got 'Failed' in it . On checking the log files for this , I found the following error ----

```
/home/portal/WebSphere/PortalServer/jcr/wp.content.repository.install/config/includes/jcr.install_cfg.xml:1106: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOf
BoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
        at com.ibm.wplc.deploy.tasks.impl.ResourceEnvProviderCreateImpl.execute(ResourceEnvProviderCreateImpl.java:86)
        at com.ibm.wplc.deploy.tasks.AbstractBaseAdminTask.executeBean(AbstractBaseAdminTask.java:541)
        at com.ibm.wplc.deploy.tasks.AbstractBaseAdminTask.executeTask(AbstractBaseAdminTask.java:525)
        at com.ibm.wplc.deploy.tasks.AbstractBaseWsAdminWrapperTask.executeTask(AbstractBaseWsAdminWrapperTask.java:395)
        at com.ibm.wplc.deploy.tasks.AbstractBaseAdminTask.execute(AbstractBaseAdminTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
        at com.ibm.wps.config.tasks.AntCallTask.execute(AntCallTask.java:133)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
        at com.ibm.wps.config.ForTask.execute(ForTask.java:103)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
        at com.ibm.wps.config.tasks.AntCallTask.execute(AntCallTask.java:133)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:668)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:187)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:150)
        at com.ibm.wps.config.ConfigEngine.process(ConfigEngine.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wps.config.ConfigEngine.main(ConfigEngine.java:219)
at com.ibm.wps.config.ConfigEngine.main(ConfigEngine.java:219)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java)
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java)
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java)
        at org.python.core.PyInstance.invoke(PyInstance.java)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx50.f$0(<string>:78)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx50.call_function(<string>)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java)
        at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java)
        at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java)
        at org.python.core.Py.exec(Py.java)
        at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java)
        at com.ibm.bsf.engines.jython.JythonEngine$BSFPythonInterpreter.exec(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.bsf.engines.jython.JythonEngine.exec(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.bsf.BSFManager$6.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:330)
        at com.ibm.bsf.BSFManager.exec(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AbstractShell.executeScript(AbstractShell.java:1214)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AbstractShell.run(AbstractShell.java:2271)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.WasxShell.main(WasxShell.java:1108)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)

at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:380)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:151)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
        at com.ibm.wplc.deploy.tasks.impl.ResourceEnvProviderCreateImpl.execute(ResourceEnvProviderCreateImpl.java:43)
        ... 83 more
--- Nested Exception ---
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
        at com.ibm.wplc.deploy.tasks.impl.ResourceEnvProviderCreateImpl.execute(ResourceEnvProviderCreateImpl.java:43)
        at com.ibm.wplc.deploy.tasks.AbstractBaseAdminTask.executeBean(AbstractBaseAdminTask.java:541)
        at com.ibm.wplc.deploy.tasks.AbstractBaseAdminTask.executeTask(AbstractBaseAdminTask.java:525)
        at com.ibm.wplc.deploy.tasks.AbstractBaseWsAdminWrapperTask.executeTask(AbstractBaseWsAdminWrapperTask.java:395)
        at com.ibm.wplc.deploy.tasks.AbstractBaseAdminTask.execute(AbstractBaseAdminTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
        at com.ibm.wps.config.tasks.AntCallTask.execute(AntCallTask.java:133)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
        at com.ibm.wps.config.ForTask.execute(ForTask.java:103)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)

at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
        at com.ibm.wps.config.tasks.AntCallTask.execute(AntCallTask.java:133)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:668)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:187)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:150)
        at com.ibm.wps.config.ConfigEngine.process(ConfigEngine.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wps.config.ConfigEngine.main(ConfigEngine.java:219)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java)
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java)
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java)
        at org.python.core.PyInstance.invoke(PyInstance.java)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx50.f$0(<string>:78)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx50.call_function(<string>)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java)
        at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java)
        at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java)
        at org.python.core.Py.exec(Py.java)
        at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java)
        at com.ibm.bsf.engines.jython.JythonEngine$BSFPythonInterpreter.exec(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.bsf.engines.jython.JythonEngine.exec(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.bsf.BSFManager$6.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:330)
        at com.ibm.bsf.BSFManager.exec(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AbstractShell.executeScript(AbstractShell.java:1214)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AbstractShell.run(AbstractShell.java:2271)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.WasxShell.main(WasxShell.java:1108)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:380)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:151)

Failed ANT script: /home/portal/WebSphere/PortalServer/jcr/wp.content.repository.install/config/includes/jcr.install_cfg.xml:1106:
Failed target: action-update-cluster-resource-environment-wp.content.repository.install
Failed task: Task name could not be determined.  Please check the line number below for target details.
Probable failed component: wp.content.repository.install
------ Target Stack Trace  ------
action-update-cluster-resource-environment-wp.content.repository.install
cluster-node-config-cluster-setup
cluster-node-config-dynamic-cluster-setup
------Target Excerpt ------
1056:                   <condition>
1057:                           <contains string="${PortalAdminId}" substring="=" casesensitive="false" />
1058:                   </condition>
1059:                   <then>
1060:                           <property name="jcr.admin.uniquename" value="${PortalAdminId}" />
1061:                   </then>
1062:                   <else>
1063:                           <property name="jcr.admin.uniquename" value="${WmmDbUserPrefix}=${PortalAdminId},${WmmDbSuffix}" />
1064:                   </else>
1065:           </if>
1066:           <!-- set custom properties common to all db2 platforms -->
1067:           <!-- forceScope="true" forces the node scoped REP to be modified, without forceScope then the cluster scoped REP is modified -->
1068:           <wplc-create-res-env-custom-property cell="${CellName}" node="${NodeName}" server="${ServerName}" wasuser="${WasUserid}" waspassword="${WasPassword}" conntype="${wsadminConnType}"
1069:                   providerName="${jcr.rep.name}">
1070:                   <resource name="jcr.database.type" value="${jcr.database.type}" required="true"/>
1071:                   <resource name="jcr.database.schema" value="${jcr.DbSchema}" required="true" />
1072:                   <resource name="jcr.admin.uniqueName" value="${jcr.admin.uniquename}" required="true" />
1073:                   <resource name="jcr.binaryValueFileDir" value="${wp.content.repository.binaryValues.dir}" required="true" />
1074:                   <resource name="jcr.query.collation.db2.enabled" value="false" required="false" />
1075:                   <resource name="jcr.textsearch.enabled" value="false" required="true" />
1076:                   <resource name="jcr.textsearch.convertor" value="com.ibm.icm.ts.convertor.WpsConvertor" required="true" />
1077:                   <resource name="jcr.textsearch.indexdirectory" value="${wp.content.repository.searchIndexes.dir}" required="true" />
1078:                   <resource name="jcr.textsearch.fullcrawl.cleanup.interval" value="120" required="true" />

1079:                   <resource name="jcr.textsearch.applicationserver.name" value="${WpsHostName}" required="true" />
1080:                   <resource name="jcr.textsearch.applicationserver.port" value="${WpsHostPort}" required="true" />
1081:                   <resource name="jcr.textsearch.PSE.type" value="localhost" required="true" />
1082:                   <resource name="jcr.textsearch.SOAP.url" value="" required="true" />
1083:                   <resource name="jcr.textsearch.EJB.IIOP.URL" value="" required="true" />
1084:                   <resource name="jcr.textsearch.EJB.EJBName" value="" required="true" />
1085:           </wplc-create-res-env-custom-property>
1086:           <!-- update ZOS specific custom properties -->
1087:           <if>
1088:                   <condition>
1089:                           <equals arg1="${jcr.database.type}" arg2="db2_zos" trim="true" casesensitive="false" />
1090:                   </condition>
1091:                   <then>
1092:                           <antcall target="create-resource-environment-provider-jcr-zos" />
1093:                   </then>
1094:           </if>
1095:    </target>
1096:    <target name="action-update-cluster-resource-environment-wp.content.repository.install">
1097:           <!-- remove cluster properties that are specific to each node -->
1098:           <wplc-remove-res-env-custom-property cell="${CellName}" node="${NodeName}" server="${ServerName}" wasuser="${WasUserid}" waspassword="${WasPassword}" providerName="${jcr.rep.name}"
1099:                   name="jcr.binaryValueFileDir" />
1100:           <!-- remove node properties that should be only defined at the cluster level -->
1101:           <!-- forceScope="true" forces the node scoped REP to be modified, without forceScope then the cluster scoped REP is modified -->
1102:           <wplc-remove-resource-env-provider cell="${CellName}" node="${NodeName}" server="${ServerName}" wasuser="${WasUserid}" waspassword="${WasPassword}" name="${jcr.rep.name}"
1103:                   forceScope="true" />
1104:           <!-- forceScope="true" forces the node scoped REP to be modified, without forceScope then the cluster scoped REP is modified -->
1105:           <wplc-create-resource-env-provider cell="${CellName}" node="${NodeName}" server="${ServerName}" wasuser="${WasUserid}" waspassword="${WasPassword}" conntype="${wsadminConnType}"
1106:**>                name="${jcr.rep.name}" description="Provider for JCR" forceScope="true">
1107:           </wplc-create-resource-env-provider>
1108:           <!-- forceScope="true" forces the node scoped REP to be modified, without forceScope then the cluster scoped REP is modified -->

ied -->
1109:           <wplc-create-res-env-custom-property cell="${CellName}" node="${NodeName}" server="${ServerName}" wasuser="${WasUserid}" waspassword="${WasPassword}" conntype="${wsadminConnType}"
1110:                   providerName="${jcr.rep.name}" forceScope="true">
1111:                   <resource name="jcr.binaryValueFileDir" value="${wp.content.repository.binaryValues.dir}" required="true" />
1112:           </wplc-create-res-env-custom-property>
1113:    </target>
1114:    <target name="create-resource-environment-provider-jcr-zos">
1115:           <!-- forceScope="true" forces the node scoped REP to be modified, without forceScope then the cluster scoped REP is modified -->
1116:           <wplc-create-res-env-custom-property cell="${CellName}" node="${NodeName}" server="${ServerName}" wasuser="${WasUserid}" waspassword="${WasPassword}" conntype="${wsadminConnType}"
1117:                   providerName="${jcr.rep.name}">
1118:                   <resource name="jcr.zos.database.stoGroup" value="${jcr.DbStorageGroup}" required="true" />
1119:                   <resource name="jcr.zos.database.unicode.enabled" value="${jcr.DbUnicode}" required="true" />
1120:                   <resource name="jcr.zos.database.blob.bufferpool" value="${jcr.blobBufferpool}" required="true" />
1121:                   <resource name="jcr.zos.database.bp4k.tables" value="${jcr.Db4KBufferPoolName}" required="true" />
1122:                   <resource name="jcr.zos.database.bp4k.indexes" value="${jcr.DbIndex4KBufferPoolName}" required="true" />
1123:                   <resource name="jcr.zos.database.bp32k.tables" value="${jcr.Db32KBufferPoolName}" required="true" />
1124:           </wplc-create-res-env-custom-property>
1125:    </target>
1126:    <target name="action-post-cluster-configuration-wp.content.repository.install">
1127:           <!-- Disable TS for primary node only -->
1128:           <if>
1129:                   <condition>
1130:                           <not>
1131:                                   <equals arg1="${isSecondNode}" arg2="true" trim="true" casesensitive="false" />
1132:                           </not>
1133:                   </condition>
1134:                   <then>
1135:                           <antcall target="action-disable-textsearch" />
1136:                   </then>
1137:           </if>
1138:    </target>

------- Properties and values used in the failed target -------
os.arch=amd64
WasUserid=wasadmin
wsadminConnType=SOAP
jcr.rep.name=JCR ConfigService PortalContent
NodeName=Node01
WasPassword=PASSWORD_REMOVED
ConfigEngineSoapTimeout=${ConfigEngineSoapTimeout}
EngineRootDir=/home/portal/WebSphere/ConfigEngine
enableAawsiTrace=${enableAawsiTrace}
EngineInstallLocation=/home/portal/WebSphere/wp_profile/ConfigEngine
WasRemoteHostName=172.16.100.31
WasSoapPort=8879
CellName=dmgrCell01
ServerName=PortalCluster_Node01
```

Can please somebody let me know what is the issue and help me to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

So it is failing on this line
1105:                           name="${jcr.rep.name}" description="Provider for JCR" forceScope="true">

Did you ensure that the cell node and server name are correct? Usually that error means it cannot find the resource provider to actually set it

Comment: The values which I have used for dmgr are ----> cell=dmgrCell01 , node=dmgrNode01 , wasuser=wasadmin . However , I am not sure how to find the server name for dmgr. The server name of my portal was WebSphere_Portal but it used PortalCluster_Node01 on its own . It also used Node01 for node name on its own in the config wizard .Also , for WAS_PASSWORD , it removed the password which I put . I don't know if the issue is created by this and how to rectify it .

Comment: in the output it usually blanks password so that it is more secure,  the way to verify names, is on the dmgr to check under the config directory of the dmgr profile and you can see what it has listed for the cells and server names

Comment: Hi, as per your suggestion, I checked the config directory of dmgr. The profile name is dmgr01, cell name is dmgrcell01, node name is Node01. Under the servers folder is WebSphere_Portal and nodeagent, of whom I suppose WebSphere_Portal is the server name only. Complete path is /home/dmgr/WebSphere/AppServer/V85/ND/profiles/dmgr01/config/cells/dmgrCell01/nodes/Node01/servers/WebSphere_Portal

Comment: Also, I found out that the server name 'PortalCluster_Node01' is coming from the 'wkplc.properties' file of portal server . Path is /home/portal/WebSphere/wp_profile/ConfigEngine/properties/wkplc.properties . The config wizard had earlier taken backup of the old wkplc.properties file in which server name was 'WebSphere_Portal'. But after running the config wizard, it automatically changed the server name to 'PortalCluster_Node01'.